# Use mapreduce to read CSVs (where not all columns match) and combine into DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, mapreduce, julia

I'm using Julia 1.4.2.

I want to use `mapreduce()` to:

1. Read a bunch of CSVs, then
2. Combine them into one big DataFrame.

First the preliminaries:

```
using CSV, DataFrames

# Create CSVs
df1 = DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]],
                ["name", "id"])
df2 = DataFrame([['d', 'e', 'f'], [4, 5, 6]],
                ["name", "id"])
# NOTE: This df has an extra column not present in the other two
df3 = DataFrame([['x', 'y', 'z'], [7, 8, 9], [11, 22, 33]],
                ["name", "id", "num"])
CSV.write("df1.csv", df1)
CSV.write("df2.csv", df2)
CSV.write("df3.csv", df3)

# Get Vector of file paths for the above-created CSVs.
# Regex because there might be other files in working directory.
files = filter(x -> occursin(r"df\d\.csv$", x),
               readdir(join=true))
```

If I call `map()` and `reduce()` separately, I get what I want:

```
# Import the above-created CSVs as a Vector of DataFrames
dfs = map(x -> CSV.File(x) |> DataFrame,
          files)

# Combine them into one big DataFrame
df = reduce(vcat, dfs, cols=:union)
```

(NOTE: `df3` has an extra column not present in the other two, so I *need* the `cols=:union` argument.)

However, I want to condense the above `map()` and `reduce()` calls into a `mapreduce()` call. Here's what I've tried:

```
df = mapreduce(x -> CSV.File(x) |> DataFrame,
               x -> vcat(x, cols=:union),
               files)
# MethodError: no method matching (::var"#16#18")(::DataFrame, ::DataFrame)

df = mapreduce(x -> CSV.File(x) |> DataFrame,
               vcat,
               files,
               cols=:union)
# MethodError: no method matching _mapreduce_dim(::var"#21#22", ::typeof(vcat), ::NamedTuple{(:cols,),Tuple{Symbol}}, ::Array{String,1}, ::Colon)
```

The root of my problem is that I don't understand the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.mapreduce-Tuple%7BAny,Any,Any%7D) for `mapreduce()`. How can I pass named arguments to the binary function (the `op` argument)? E.g., I can add the `cols=:union` argument to `reduce(op, itr)`, as in `reduce(vcat, dfs, cols=:union)`. How can I pass arguments to the binary function `op` in `mapreduce(f, op, itrs...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`op` must be a two-argument function since it combines the current state with the newly mapped element. Try this:

```
df = mapreduce(x -> CSV.File(x) |> DataFrame,
               (x, y) -> vcat(x, y; cols=:union),
               files)
```

Comment: This is a correct pattern to use `mapreduce`, but please note that doing what you did originally will be much faster as `reduce` on a collection of `DataFrames` is optimized, while `mapreduce` pattern is not.

Comment: The difference is that if `reduce` is passed a collection of data frames it can allocate the destination data frame in one shot and `mapreduce` approach creates many intermediate data frames that get discared in the process.